# Storing large files / binary data in a mysql database: when is it ok?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, database, binary

Ok, I have searched about this and read a few points of view about storing binary data in a [MySQL] database. Generally I consider this a bad idea and try to avoid it, favouring traditional file transfers and just storing a reference to the file in a database.

However, I am working on a project which requires database synchronisation with a remote/cloud database, not just for files, but also for settings and other user content. For this, and other reasons, I felt this might be an appropriate situation for binary storage in a database.

I have written a general system for the database sync which works well using Reflection and XML. I have also (against my instincts) integrated the file storage in to this system. Again, it works well - I chop files in to 64Kb BLOBs and store them in a table, with a file_id reference (linked to a seperate table which contains meta data such as file name/size/mime type).

This enables me to send bits and pieces as and when a connection is available, and also allows me to limit each request size to keep things running smoothly.

So far I have not found any issues with this, and have successfully imported and transferred over 1gb of data in both directions (over about 10-15 files / 16000 rows), but I worry about its scalability - will it slow down once there is 20gb+ data in there, or can MySQL handle it provided my queries are well structured?

Another reason for my decision to store the data in the database was that I figured I could simply add another HDD/storage device to MySQL if space ran low, in the hope of efficient scaling/replication/etc.

I would very much appreciate any views or comments as to whether this is a good or bad approach, and have I missed any obvious problems I'm likely to see once used in a production environment?

edit: I forgot to mention, the file sizes could range from 1KB to ~1GB

**[Rough] Conclusion**
Firstly: thanks very much to those who contributed a considered answer. Choosing the accepted answer here has been quite difficult as each has something decent to offer.

In the end (despite my hopes), I have decided that a pure MySQL storage server is at best only an ok solution (I still can't help wondering why they bother including the BLOB types though).

As the alternative, I am torn between @Nick Coons file system approach and @tadman's suggestion of a hybrid using a light weight key/value database engine such as leveldb. Provided the practicalities of using leveldb in this project are not an issue, this is most likely the approach I will work towards.

I have accepted tadman's answer on this basis; his answer was also most applicable and useful to my situation.

That being said, and for those that are interested: I have enjoyed quite a lot of success using only MySQL so far. I have tested a table storing over 15gb of binary data without any noticable negative side effects from to inserting/retrieving data from large tables (with careful queries). However, I am certain this is still very inefficient and either of the alternative methods mentioned will be significantly better.

Comment: If you are going to down-vote, please can you at least provide an explanation so I can avoid the same mistake again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to wonder why you're even bothering with a database at all, when the layer you've added on top to chunk, store, retrieve and reassemble would work just as well on a well-defined filesystem structure. MySQL wants all of its data on a *single* volume, so it's not a case of adding another drive whenever you feel like it, and replication of large amounts of binary data is going to be cripplingly slow as the binary logs will end up duplicating the amount of data you need to store.

The simplest approach is often the best one. Storing this in the filesystem directly is probably the best way to do it. If you need to keep an index of what's stored where, maybe you'd use a database like MySQL, but there's many ways to accomplish this same task. The more low-tech, the better. For example, don't rule out [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) because an embedded database performs very well under light read and write load, and has the advantage of being "just a file" when it comes to backing up and restoring.

That being said, what you're doing sounds suspiciously similar to [LevelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/), so before you commit to your approach, you'd have to see how it's significantly different than a key-value document store of that variety.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you raise some interesting ideas. The project already uses a WAMP environment for various other tasks, so I thought I may as well utilise what was already there. Also I had a look at LevelDB and it looks great, but I don't think it's quite right for my needs on this occasion: "It does not have a relational data model, it does not support SQL queries, and it has no support for indexes". I can't help thinking that will cause me more problems. The reason for using the database in the first place was just that I had already set up the infrastructure for the other sync items

Comment: Your point about the binary logs is quite alarming though, so I think I will consider moving towards a 'proper' file system - do you think it would be ok to still use the database sync to transfer, before assembling to binary on the other side (and then deleting binary from the database)? Using the database allows me to keep an accurate track of which blocks of data have and haven't been received (there could be a possibility they won't be received in order)

Comment: Databases are very good at storing well-defined relational data. They are awful at storing large amounts of arbitrary binary data. What you might use is a hybrid, a LevelDB data store with an RDBMS index built on top. LevelDB is great at storing enormous amounts of data, and can be replicated using standard tools like `rsync`.

Comment: Hi @tadman, thanks for your input. I have had another look at levelDB, and see that I could use MySQL for the relational side and store the levelDB keys/ranges as reference values to use both. Is this the sort of thing you had in mind? Still, I do have the issue that I basically need to duplicate whatever I make: I need a C# system for the desktop application in a WAMP environment, and a PHP equivalent in a LAMP environment (typical web host). Forgive my ignorance, but afaik, leveldb isn't available by default on most web hosts?

Comment: There's a number of PHP LevelDB extensions you can always add on, so that shouldn't be an issue. Hopefully you're not using some kind of atrocious shared hosting where you have zero control over your stack. If LevelDB doesn't work out, you can always manage the files manually, but it's just a lot more work. LevelDB will chunk, organize, and prune data as you add and remove things, and the built-in transparent compression is another perk. You could write all that yourself, but it's a lot of work. It's like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) as an embedded library.

Comment: That sounds ideal - it would be the icing on the cake if you could point me in the direction of the best of those extensions? And I certainly do not want to reinvent the wheel: no point doing what other people have already done better :)

Comment: I found that one too.. just wanted to make sure I wasn't choosing mysql over pdo, if you know what I mean - thanks.

Comment: That looks like a really feature complete library, so I'd be comfortable using it.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:**

I'm not sure there's a hard-lined way to answer this. You mentioned files being from 1KB to 1GB.. I wouldn't store binary data in a DB if it's going to anywhere near 1KB, let along 1GB.  I may store a few bytes of binary data in a DB if it's incidental, but any large amount of data, especially that doesn't need to be searched, should be stored in the filesystem:

When you store data in a DB, you're storing it on a filesystem anyway, you've just added another layer (the DB) to the mix.  There's a cost to this layer, so there ought to be a benefit to make up the difference.  If you're storing the data so that you can search based on it or join it to other data, then this makes sense.  But file data, binary or not, is typically not used in that way.

**Example Implementation:**

There are better methods to distribute file data than to enter it into a DB, such as a distributed filesystems (check into GlusterFS, MooseFS, both of which will scale by simply adding additional hard drives, whereas MySQL will not).

Typically, I'll store file data in the filesystem using an SHA1 hash of the data as the name of the file.  If the hash is 98a75af529f07b1ef7be7400f51344b9f07b1ef7, then I'll store it in this directory structure:

```
./98/a7/98a75af529f07b1ef7be7400f51344b9f07b1ef7
```

That is, a top-level directory made up of the first two characters, a second-level directory made up of the second two characters, and then finally the file with the name of the total string.  In this way, I can literally have billions of files without having so many in a single directory that the system is too slow to function.

Then I create a DB table with these columns to hold the meta data:

- file_id, an auto_increment field
- created, a field with a default value of current_timestamp
- prev_id, more on this below
- hash, the SHA1 hash on the filesystem
- name, a textual name of the file (such as the original name that the file would have taken on disk.

When I need a hierarchical directory structure, I would also create a directory table and add a dir_id to the list of columns above.

If I edit the file represented by `./98/a7/98a75af529f07b1ef7be7400f51344b9f07b1ef7`, I don't actually change that file on disk, I create a new one (because the new file contents would be represented by a new SHA1 hash), and create a new entry in the files table where prev_id equals the file_id of the file I edited.  In other words, I now have versioning.

If I need this to be available in a distributed fashion, I setup MySQL replication and then use GlusterFS to replicate he filesystem across multiple servers.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it's a very good answer. I particularly like your suggested file storage method. It would also be nice to use a distributed filesystem as you mentioned, but unfortunately we are not working with dedicated servers (for the time being at least). I need to try and make this as compatible as possible with typical shared web hosting setups, which of course makes it difficult to use anything which needs installing on the server. But again, thank you for the elegant file system method :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find a fair amount of debate on this as I did when I began looking into this. I tend to lean toward storing in the file system and maintaining a reference. However, that is not to say that there is never a time to store binary data in a database.

I would say that simply to keep things in sync is not a reason within itself to make an argument for storing binary data in a database. There certainly are ways to keep file systems in sync so that as a database is kept in sync so is the file system.

The bottom line is that there is a fair amount of debate on this topic and you have to go with what works for you. If what you have set up works. Use it. Do performance and load testing to make sure it works. If it doesn't hold up, change it.

Comment: You're right - I have found a lot of debate about this.. but, that's why I asked :) Since posting, I have been doing more testing, and now have a table containing around 15gb of data, with some files as large as 1.2gb, and everything seems fine so far :) But, tempted as I am to leave it alone, the points raised in the other answers leave me with a bad feeling. Also, with regards to your second paragraph, I opted for this just because I already had a robust serialisation/sync engine I can add objects to quite easily: so, a mixture of laziness and hope I suppose :)